# PHP compare two arrays of dates and check for match

Tags: php, arrays

I want have two `arrays` with date objects which I want to compare. The first array contains todays date and the next five days:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$fiveDays = [];
for($i=0; $i <= 5; $i++){
    $today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($today)));
    $fiveDays[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today));
}
```

which gives the result:

```
0: "2018-09-14"
1: "2018-09-15"
2: "2018-09-16"
3: "2018-09-17"
4: "2018-09-18"
5: "2018-09-19"
```

the other array can contain multiple objects:

```
[{
   days: (4) ["2018-09-13", "2018-09-14", "2018-09-15", "2018-09-16"]
   duration: 4
   end: "2018-09-16"
   name: "vacation blabla"
   start: "2018-09-13"
},
{
   days: (5) ["2018-09-20", "2018-09-21", "2018-09-22", "2018-09-23", "2018-09-24"]
   duration: 5
   end: "2018-09-24"
   name: "vacation blabla"
   start: "2018-09-20"
}]
```

Now I want to check if one of the days/dates of the first array will or is in the vacations_array. How can I achieve that?

**EDIT**

When a match is found, the second array(with the vacation-periods) where the match is true, must be assigned to a `$vacation`-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way too:

```
$result_array = array();
$found = false;
for($i=0; $i<count($vacation_array); $i++) {
  $found = false;
  for($j=0; $j<count($vacation_array[$i]['days']); $j++) {
    if(in_array($vacation_array[$i]['days'][$j], $array_1) && !$found) {
      $result_array[] = $vacation_array[$i];
      $found = true;
    }
  }
}
print_r($result_array);
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks a million times! :-)

Comment: @ST80 Sure thing!

Answer (score 2):

use array_intersect()

Basically you do this within a loop for array 2:

```
$array_of_same_elements = array_intersect($array_1, $array_2[$i]['days']);
```

$array_of_same_elements will now contain the dates you are looking for.

A nice description of this is found here:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_intersect.asp

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work, even though it seems correct

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly does happen? Error Message?

Comment: I have updated my question, please look... When a match is found, the second array(with the vacation-periods) where the match is true, must be assigned to a $vacation-array

Comment: Then refere to Steve Kirsches Answer.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit simple but it may fit your needs:

```
$event1 = ['days'=>["2018-09-13", "2018-09-14", "2018-09-15", "2018-09-16"]];
$event2 = ['days'=>["2018-09-20", "2018-09-21", "2018-09-22", "2018-09-23", "2018-09-24"]];

function checkEvents($ev1, $ev2){
    foreach($ev1 AS $day){
       if(in_array($day, $ev2)){
          return $day." is found in both events\n";
       }
    }
    return "no match found\n";
}

echo checkEvents($event1['days'], $event2['days']);
```